# Parse HTML table rows to multidimensional array, with key and values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually using this method, but it only returns me an array of arrays of values, I need a way to set a key and value, setting each key to `<td>` name property would be fine.
If you have any solution in mind, please share.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td name="name">Juan</td>
    <td name="age">23</td>
    <td name="random">1990</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td name="name">Jonhatan</td>
    <td name="age">25</td>
    <td name="random">1980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td name="name">Pete</td>
    <td name="age">20</td>
    <td name="random">1991</td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#output').html('OUTPUT: '+tableToJson('#mytable'));
});

function tableToJson(table){
    var AoA = $(table+' tr').map(function(){
        return [
            $('td',this).map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get()
        ];
    }).get();
    return JSON.stringify(AoA);
}
```

**Current output:**

```
[["Juan","23","1990"],["Jonhatan","25","1980"],["Pete","20","1991"]]
```

**Output needed:**

```
[
[{'name':"Juan"},{'age':"23"},{'random':"1990"}],
[{'name':"Jonhatan",{'age':"25"},{'random':"1980"}],
[{'name':"Pete"},{'age':"20"},{'random':"1991"}]
]
```

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/j4x7pr2w/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j4x7pr2w/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tableToJson(table){
    var AoA = $(table).find('tr').map(function(){
        var result = {};
        $('td',this).each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            result[$this.attr('name')] = $this.text();
        });
        return result;
    }).get();
    return JSON.stringify(AoA);
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `$(table).find("tr")` (that way you can pass an element or more complex selector as the argument).

Comment: @soktinpk: Yes, true. I changed the code minimally from OP's, and didn't look closer at the surroundings. But you are correct, and it makes sense to change it.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/mLr1tatt/)

The following code should fix it. It's basically an outer `.each()` with an inner `.map()`.

```
$(function() {
    var AoA = [];
    $('#mytable').find('tr').each(function(i,tr) {
        var BoB = $(tr).find('td').map(function(j,td) {
            var thisTD = {};
            thisTD[ $(td).attr('name') ] = $(td).html();
            return thisTD;
        }).get();
        AoA.push( BoB );        
    });
    $('body').append( JSON.stringify( AoA ) );
});
```